# Qt Qml Vertical Tabbar

Tags: qt, qml, vertical-alignment, tabbar

I would like to add Vertical TabBar to my app in a similar manner of what Qt Creater is doing in their app (as shown in picture).
I have been searching how to simple make the TabBar vertical, yet did not find proper answers (thought its common to have it vertical).

**Question:** How could I make a **Vertical Tab** to navigate through the different qml files I have? If there are more suitable options, please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A TabBar just uses a common `ListView` to display a bunch of `TabButtons`. You can customize it by overwriting the `contentItem` property and making the ListView vertical, like this:

```
// VertTabBar.qml
TabBar {
    id: control

    contentItem: ListView {
        model: control.contentModel
        currentIndex: control.currentIndex

        spacing: control.spacing
        orientation: ListView.Vertical   // <<-- VERTICAL
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        flickableDirection: Flickable.AutoFlickIfNeeded
        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem

        highlightMoveDuration: 0
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.ApplyRange
        preferredHighlightBegin: 40
        preferredHighlightEnd: height - 40
    }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering, is this the common way to go with or are there better common solutions for example using TabBar with different implementation or TabTool or Drawer or ... ?

Comment: If you have different solutions in mind, feel free to use them. There's no "right way" to do things. But Qt Quick Controls are designed to be easy to customize, and this looks pretty easy and straightforward to me.

Comment: The TabBar I'm implementing will be fixed at left side in all qml Windows. Therefore I just used the Vertical orientation and added TabButtons inside contentItem (also tried outside it). But still the buttons are on top of each other at upper left corner of the window. I'm trying to fix this behavior.

Comment: I've tested my code, and it works as expected. When you created your TabBar, did you specify the height?

Comment: My bad, it works fine after adding height, thanks. Now I'll give it more customization to fit properly as needed with the other windows and not appear on top of them.

Comment: Note that `ListView` is by default vertical so you don't need to specify orientation.

Answer (score 0):

**A complete example using Fusion theme.**

**It is important to set the width of the TabButton** else the width is divided by the number of items.

**Notice** there is a light colour separator line, that comes from ???

**Issue: first item can be partially clipped.**

Well, there are a lot of things under the hood with QML...

**Thus, we cannot really make a TabBar vertical...**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

import QtQuick.Templates as T
// import QtQuick.Controls.impl
// import QtQuick.Controls.Fusion
// import QtQuick.Controls.Fusion.impl

Page {
    id: root
    width: 1800
    height: 800

    Row {
        anchors.fill: parent

        TabBar {
            id: control
            width: 200
            height: parent.height

            contentItem: ListView {
                model: control.contentModel
                currentIndex: control.currentIndex

                spacing: control.spacing
                orientation: ListView.Vertical
                boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
                flickableDirection: Flickable.AutoFlickIfNeeded
                snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem

                highlightMoveDuration: 0
                highlightRangeMode: ListView.ApplyRange
                preferredHighlightBegin: 40
                preferredHighlightEnd: width - 40
            }

            Repeater {
                model: 50
                TabButton {
                    id: control2
                    width: control.width
                    text: "tab blabla blabla %1".arg(model.index)

                    contentItem: IconLabel {
                        spacing: control2.spacing
                        mirrored: control2.mirrored
                        display: control2.display

                        icon: control2.icon
                        text: control2.text
                        font: control2.font
                        color: control2.palette.buttonText
                    }

                    background: Rectangle {
                        y: control2.checked || control2.TabBar.position !== T.TabBar.Header ? 0 : 2
                        implicitHeight: 21
                        height: control2.height - (control2.checked ? 0 : 2)

                        border.color: Qt.lighter(Fusion.outline(control2.palette), 1.1)
                        border.width: 0

                        gradient: Gradient {
                            GradientStop {
                                position: 0
                                color: control2.checked ? Qt.lighter(Fusion.tabFrameColor(control2.palette), 1.04)
                                    : Qt.darker(Fusion.tabFrameColor(control2.palette), 1.08)
                            }
                            GradientStop {
                                position: control2.checked ? 0 : 0.85
                                color: control2.checked ? Qt.lighter(Fusion.tabFrameColor(control2.palette), 1.04)
                                    : Qt.darker(Fusion.tabFrameColor(control2.palette), 1.08)
                            }
                            GradientStop {
                                position: 1
                                color: control2.checked ? Fusion.tabFrameColor(control2.palette)
                                    : Qt.darker(Fusion.tabFrameColor(control2.palette), 1.16)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        StackLayout {
            id: stack_layout
            width: parent.width - 200
            height: parent.height

            currentIndex: control.currentIndex

            Repeater {
                model: 50
                Item {
                    Label {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "tab %1".arg(model.index)
                        font.pixelSize: 50
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```